# mongodb Sharding lookup not working

Tags: mongodb, lookup, sharding

Can we perform `$lookup` in a sharding. If yes, can you suggest an example? I don't want to change the schema of my database.

Eg:

```
db.unshared_collection.aggregate([
  {
   $lookup:{ 'from' : 'shared_collection','localField' : 'localField', 'foreignField' : 'foreignField',
'as' : 'location'}}])
```

Thanks.....

Comment: You should edit your database schema and change it to code so it easy to read

Comment: Add a sample document from your collections

Comment: @InnocentAnigbo  thanks for your update. But i have already tried by changing the schema                                      db.shared_collection.aggregate([
  {
   $lookup:{ 'from' : 'unshared_collection','localField' : 'localField', 'foreignField' : 'foreignField',
'as' : 'location'}}])

Comment: @InnocentAnigbo  thanks for your update. But i have already tried by changing the schema                                      db.shared_collection.aggregate([
  {
   $lookup:{ 'from' : 'unshared_collection','localField' : 'localField', 'foreignField' : 'foreignField',
'as' : 'location'}}]) . but i dont want to have this schema.

Comment: @ClementAmarnath do you want a sample query?

Comment: @clementAmarnath yes. Can you share a sample query